# Specflow and Angular JS Unit Testing

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, specflow

I have been a fan of BDD type testcases..Is it possible to combine Specflow with Angular JS Unit Testing (Jasmine?)

Has anyone ever tried it?

Comment: SpecFlow is the .NET implementation of Cucumber. I think you are looking for Cucumber-js (https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js).

Answer (score 1):

Specflow is a .Net version of Cucumber, you can use protractor, the e2e test tool for angular with cucumber though here is the git library for it.

https://github.com/andrewkeig/protractor-cucumber